# Associate information from two different sources (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

We want to implement a new Oracle Database in order to store part information. The first part would be a table with a column for an identification number (string) and another column with images (BLOB).
The identification number is read by a lector connected to a pc and available as a string of X digits. After reading the identification number of the part, an image of the same part is taken (connected to a different pc) and saved to C:\Folder.

How do I associate the identification number and the image in the table? I need the two values in the same row so that querying the blob with the identification number is possible.